# What is the best way to store video stream?

Tags: database, file, mediastore, video-recording

I am working on a video recorder.

We get permanent video streams from multiple video sources (around 100 video sources totally 400 Mbps).

We should store them, retrieve them in multiple speeds when playback is needed and circularly remove older data when storage is full.

What is the best way to store these data: storing in a giant file, multiple files or store as data blobs in a database.

Note that on power outage, we need to retrieve last stored data as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can store video sources in `AWS (Amazone Web Service)` Which provide large storage to store data. For that you can use `s3BucketService` for that, Which is cloud storage for the Internet.

Here is the reference link 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is a local recorder, our storage is local disk drive.